# Controlling a 12V solenoid lock with 3.3V - IRLZ44N

Tags: arduino, mosfet, solenoid-valve

I would like to drive a solenoid lock from a 3.3 V MCU with a N-channel [IRLZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725) MOSFET.

**Here are the specs and diagram:**

**Solenoid Lock:** 12 V – 2 A (K02-12V DC 2A Electric Magnetic)

Below is the diagram where:

- **VCC:** 12 V (Korad KA3005D Power Supply)
- **SV1_CONN:** Solenoid Lock Connector
- **SV1:** 3.3 V signal from MCU (Arduino Pro Mini 3.3 V)
- **GND:** Common ground shared with the MCU

[image]

---

**My problem/questions:**

1. Although it is stated that it is a "logic-level gate drive" where "Gate Threshold Voltage: 1<VGS<2" in the MOSFET [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725), MOSFET is acting weirdly with a gate voltage of 3.3 V. Current draw of the solenoid starts (t=0) at ~800 mA, starts rising and reaches to ~1.8 a in ~10 seconds. (It is like, mosfet is opening slowly).

- Why does it take 10 seconds for the current to rise to 1.8 A (Gate: 3.3 V)? While working perfectly with a gate voltage of 5.0. .
- Is using a IRLZ44N a wrong choice?

2. Do I need any additional elements between the mcu pin and mosfet gate to protect the MCU in the long run (other then the gate resistor, 82R)? Like an optocoupler?

Comment: How much current is your 3.3 V signal capable of supplying? Can it drive the FET's gate on fast enough? It needs to charge a 1.7 nF capacitor.

Comment: I am using an Arduino Pro Mini (3.3V version) with a max current per I/O pin is 40 mA.

Comment: 2. Avoid optocoupler if you can.

Comment: What's the reason for not using an optocoupler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rds(on) is only guaranteed with a minimum drive voltage of 4.0V. 3.3V is less than 4.0V.

Possibly the MOSFET is heating up which typically decreases the Vgs for a given current. If you got the IRLZ44 from some dodgy source it's possible it does not meet specs. Although it's bad design to use an IRLZ44 with 3.3V drive, I would expect it to typically work under nominal conditions. That kind of time constant sounds like thermal or possibly leakage (as in an open or almost open connection to the gate).

There are many, many MOSFETs which are rated with 3V, 2.5V and even 1.8V drive, but few, if any, in a through-hole package. [Here](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MCU90N02(DPAK).pdf) is one example, 0.005\$\Omega\$ maximum with 2.5V drive and 0.075\$\Omega\$ maximum with 1.8V drive.

If the MOSFET fails with a drain-gate short it could damage (ie. destroy) the MCU. Electrical noise could reset the MCU. You could use an optocoupler or add some transistors to drive the MOSFET which would provide protection. You might also be worried about the solenoid lock being destroyed if the MOSFET fails on- I think most of them are only rated for very intermittent duty.

Comment: A gate-drain short is one of the least likely modes of failure; gate-source shorts are more common and wouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had couple of 2n2222's at the lab. Able to drive the IRLZ44, like you mentioned at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/518977/153952. (with an addition of 10 kΩ pull-down resistor for 3.3 V signal).

Answer (score 1):

> Although it is stated that it is a "logic-level gate drive" where "Gate Threshold Voltage: 1<VGS<2" in the mosfet datasheet, mosfet is acting weirdly with a gate voltage of 3.3V.

[image]

It is specified for Vgs of 4V, but not 3V3.

> Why does it take 10 seconds for the current to rise to 1.8 amps (Gate: 3.3v)? While working perfectly with a gate voltage of 5.0v.

Most MOSFETs have negative tempco on their threshold voltage, and positive tempco on RdsON.

My guess is that there isn't enough voltage on the gate to turn it on fully. You can confirm this by measuring Vds and Id, which will give you RdsON. If it is much higher than the specified datasheet RdsON, then it's not turned on enough. So the MOSFET works in linear mode, and as it heats up, its threshold voltage decreases, which means it turns on more, and current increases. If current increases over 10 seconds, you should feel the MOSFET get hotter.

You either need a MOSFET that will turn on with a Vgs below 3V3 (so, another MOSFET). If you have a 5V power supply on your board, you can use a 3V3 to 5V level converter/driver, for example a 74HCT logic gate, to drive this MOSFET with 5V.